# Displaylink driver - Turning folder back into .run

Tags: release-freya

I just installed elementary OS, but I can't get the Ubuntu display link driver to work with my smart dock (to connect external screens). Once I go through and activate the `.run` from their driver, I ended up stuck at the UDEV rule. Fortunately I found someone who had a similar problem and they managed to [fix it](http://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=64014).

However, once I have made the appropriate changes, I have absolutely no idea how to turn this folder that was generated from a `.run` that I can execute to get my driver working.

Comment: your question is how to run `.run` file, correct?

Comment: @Ravan It's how to make my folder (that's no longer a compressed .run file) back into a .run file so that I can run it.

Comment: This worked perfectly "right out of the box"! Wow. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with this too so I modified [AdnanHodzic's](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian) code to run on elementary. You can find the source here https://github.com/jpopesculian/displaylink-debian

1. Do a git clone: `git clone https://github.com/jpopesculian/displaylink-debian.git`
2. And run the file: `displaylink-debian/displaylink-debian.sh`

Let me know if that works for you!